# Menu won't correctly animate with jQuery show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a horizontal button menu that I am animating with jQuery and jQuery UI to hide with the "blind" effect and then show again with the "blind" effect in order to cover up the removal of one menu and loading of another via AJAX. The problem is that while the menu hides itself correctly, the "show" part doesn't animate and it appears as if the new menu just pops in.

```js
$(container).hide("blind", { direction: "down" }, 500, function() {
  $(container).html("");
  Object.keys(buttons).forEach((key, i) => {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        // get HTML for each button
      })
      .always(function(msg) {
        $(container).append("<div class='button'>" + label + "</div>");
      });
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  });
  $(container).show("blind", { direction: "down" }, 500);
});
```

Edit: One thing I've tried is not removing the HTML of the container during the show/hide process and that solves the show/hide animation problem (though it's unusable because then it becomes a menu that keeps adding more buttons). This seems to suggest that the "show" animation is being called on an empty container and there isn't enough time between the "hide" completing and the "show" starting to fill the menu back up with content. Forcing synchronous behavior seems like the most straightforward solution, but that comes with some drawbacks, so I'll try doing a setTimeout on the "show" operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this issue on my own after some further experimentation. It's a bit convoluted, but it works.

```
$(container).hide("blind", { direction: "down" }, 500, function() {
  $(container).html("");
  Object.keys(buttons).forEach((key, i, key_array) => {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        // get HTML for each button
      })
      .always(function(msg) {
        $(container).append("<div class='button'>" + label + "</div>");
        if(i === (key_array.length - 1)) {                           
          setTimeout(function () {
            $(container).show("blind", {direction: "down"}, 500);
          },
          250);
        }
      });
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  });
});
```

Basically what I'm doing now is checking that my array of buttons is at the final element before initiating the "show" effect and even then I'm putting it on a timeout of 250ms to give the browser time to load everything first (if it hasn't already). There's a few more conditions that can be added like checking if a certain element (the button or its container) has length and possibly even adding a while loop or similar to check for the presence of this last element constantly, but this is the simplified version.